# Promise Chaining

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Hi I am trying to implement Promise Chaining Using q-library in my angular project below are my 2 methods and the way they are chained.I have also posted method implementations to understand my problem. Now in `pathUserDataFromAuthService` method I would like to access the Etag value that i have set in the first Promise i.e `getUserDataFromAuthServer` using `setEtag()` method , The problem here is `getEtag()` method is called before the first promise data is resolved .

How would ensure that correct Etag value is coming up

Any help in this regard would be great

```
  getUserDataFromAuthServer(user)
            .then(pathUserDataFromAuthService(user))
```

and  the method code is as below

```
    getUserDataFromAuthServer = function(user){
                    var defer=$q.defer();
                    $http.get(autherizationURL+'/'+'api/users/'+user.username)
                   .then(function(response){
                        var ETag =response.headers().etag;
                        console.log("etag"+ETag)
                        setEtag(ETag)
                        console.log("Etag Set changed");
                        defer.resolve(response.data);
                    },function(error){          
                          defer.reject(error.statusText);
                    });
                    return defer.promise;       
                };



            var pathUserDataFromAuthService = function (user){      
                var defer=$q.defer();
                var passwordtobesaved ={
                        "firstName": user.firstName,
                        "lastName": user.lastName
                    };
                var tag = getEtag();
            $http.put(autherizationURL+'/'+'api/users/'+user.username,passwordtobesaved,{
                    headers:{
                        "If-Match": tag
                    }
                }).then(function(response){

                    defer.resolve(response.data);
                },function(error){          
                      defer.reject(error.statusText);
                });
                return defer.promise;       
            };
```

Comment: First of all, [avoid the deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: You must pass a callback *function* to `then`, not a promise (the result of calling a function)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use defer, this is an anti-pattern.
You can simply pass on the promise by returning the http request.

Here's how it should be:

```
getUserDataFromAuthServer = function(user){
  return $http.get(autherizationURL+'/'+'api/users/'+user.username)
      .then(function(response){
           var ETag =response.headers().etag;
           console.log("etag"+ETag)
           setEtag(ETag)
           console.log("Etag Set changed");
           return response.data;
        }
};
```

Same thing can be done in your second function, although I don't see why it's needed since you do nothing when it ends.

```
var pathUserDataFromAuthService = function (user){      
  var passwordtobesaved ={
    "firstName": user.firstName,
    "lastName": user.lastName
  };
  var tag = getEtag();
  return $http.put(
    autherizationURL + '/' + 'api/users/' + user.username, 
    passwordtobesaved, 
    { headers: { "If-Match": tag } }
  )
};
```

Comment: I am using the Etag from the first Request and while posting it to the server i need the Etag value so the server makes an Optimistic Lock on the Object

Comment: I've added the second function as well

Comment: You'd have to use `throw error.statusText` though (even if rejecting with/throwing strings is in itself an antipattern)

Comment: A small comment - better use camel case for variables. passwordtobesaved => passwordToBeSaved

Comment: @Bergi So just change the `return` to `throw` in the error function?

Comment: @AsafDavid: Yes, the `deferrerd.reject` the OP had is equivalent to a `throw`

Comment: @Bergi what if I just remove the error function? Will he be able to catch the error at the same place he catches the promise?

Comment: @AsafDavid: If you omit the error handler, the resulting promise will be rejected with the same reason as the one `then` was called upon. It just bubbles through.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the main issue is that `then()` accepts *function(s)*.

After that, the need to pass `user` makes things slightly awkward but nothing that javascript can't cope with.

A number of approaches are possible. Here are two.

**1. Pass `user` and `etag` separately, with the help of `.bind()`**

It's maybe not obvious how this works because the two parameters `user` and `etag` are passed by different mechanisms :

- `user`: is "bound"
- `etag`: is delivered by the promise chain to the function returned by `.bind()`

```
getUserDataFromAuthServer(user).then(pathUserDataFromAuthService.bind(null, user));

getUserDataFromAuthServer = function(user) {
    return $http.get(autherizationURL + '/api/users/' + user.username).then(function(response) {
        return response.headers().etag;
    });
};

var pathUserDataFromAuthService = function(user, etag) {
    return $http.put(autherizationURL + '/api/users/' + user.username, {
        "firstName": user.firstName,
        "lastName": user.lastName
    }, {
        headers: { "If-Match": etag }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

**2. Deliver `user` and `etag` as properties of a single object**

This is probably more intuitive. The promise chain delivers a single object to `pathUserDataFromAuthService` as `data`.

```
getUserDataFromAuthServer(user).then(pathUserDataFromAuthService);

getUserDataFromAuthServer = function(user) {
    return $http.get(autherizationURL + '/api/users/' + user.username).then(function(response) {
        return {
            user: user,
            etag: response.headers().etag
        };
    });
};

var pathUserDataFromAuthService = function(data) {
    return $http.put(autherizationURL + '/api/users/' + data.user.username, {
        "firstName": data.user.firstName,
        "lastName": data.user.lastName
    }, {
        headers: { "If-Match": data.etag }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

In both solutions `setEtag()` / `getEtag()` disappear on the assumption that they existed (in the question) solely as a mechanism for passing `ETag`. If necessary for other reasons (eg side-effects), they can be reintroduced without consequence (unless they throw).